Variable transformation from quasiconvex to convex optimization problem
Let t and b be real numbers, a and x n-dimensional real vectors. In the solution below, the quasiconvex problem is converted into a convex one thorugh a change of variables. I don't understand why the change of variables requires  \begin{array}{ll}
&& \|\hat{a}\|_2 \leq 1 / t \end{array}
I have tried computing the Jacobian of the transformation and it's determinant, but I couldn't derive the expression.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{maximize} & t \\
\text { subject to } & a^T x+b \geq 1+t\|a\|_2 \quad \text { if } x \in C_1 \\
& a^T x+b \leq-\left(1+t\|a\|_2\right) \quad \text { if } x \in C_2
\end{array}
$$
This is a quasiconvex optimization problem. It can be solved by bisection on $t$, via a sequence of SOCP feasibility problems.
A better method is to make the problem convex by a change of variables
$$
\hat{a}=\frac{1}{1+t\|a\|_2} a, \quad \hat{b}=\frac{1}{1+t\|a\|_2} b
$$
We have to add the constraint $\|\hat{a}\|_2 \leq 1 / t$ to ensure that the change of variables is invertible. This gives
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{maximize} & t \\
\text { subject to } & \hat{a}^T x+\hat{b} \geq 1 \quad \forall x \in C_1 \\
& \hat{a}^T x+\hat{b} \leq-1 \quad \forall x \in C_2 \\
& \|\hat{a}\|_2 \leq 1 / t
\end{array}
This is a part of a problem from Boyd - Convex Optimization - Additional Exercises problem (8.4 in the link below).
https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxbook_additional_exercises/blob/main/additional_exercises.pdf.

What are $C_1,C_2$? It is painful to skip through the link (which is considered bad from on MSE since links can disappear). What are the design variables?

C1 and C2 are convex closed sets in Rn

The reason the constraint is required is actually quite obvious. It basically ensures that the norm of a_hat is positive.
